# Переход по ссылке js

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу узнать у опытных программистов, возможно ли реализовать переход по ссылке, но так чтоб оказаться на определенном блоке страницы, а не в ее начале, по типу якоря в лендингах? Т.е я кликаю на кнопку, открывается страница, но не на самом ее начале, а на конкретном блоке? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну собственно якорь и использовать. [Этот ответ.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608081/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5-js/608084#608084)

Answer (score 1):

Просто в линке на нужный элемент, через `#` указываешь его `id`, получив ссылку формата: `somelink.com/somepage#someEl`

Answer (score 0):

`#якорь` (в ссылке) и описание якорей на блоках не помогает разве?

Comment: @Yuri, да вроде содержится... Такой же, как в двух соседних ответах.